# PHP script running on terminal but not in background

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I'm getting the weird error, trying to figure it out since a day with no clue.

I've a script at `/home/myname/script.php` which contains

```
 <?php
while(True) {
    echo "You said: ".$argv[1];
    sleep(5);
}
```

When I run directly on terminal like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/myname/script.php hello
```

I'm getting the expected output and the script doesn't stop. But if I do

```
/usr/bin/php /home/myname/script.php hello &
```

it is stopping immediately instead of running in background, like this.

```
[1]+  Stopped  /usr/bin/php /home/myname/script.php hello
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989161/running-php-script-from-command-line-as-background-process

Comment: Thanks. Using `nohup` solved the problem. But it is supposed to run without `nohup`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nohup /usr/bin/php /home/myname/script.php hello &` .

To validate you can re-direct your output to `nohup /usr/bin/php /home/myname/script.php hello > log.txt &`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
nohup php file.php &
```

or avoid sending output to nohup.out

```
nohup php file.php &> /dev/null
```

To run it in the background without nohup, put:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

at the begining of the php code.

By default, the php file terminates when the user aborts it (whether its on the server or running on the terminal) and putting it in the background somehow makes it think its been aborted.

Also:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

will keep it running incase there is a max_execution_time limit set in your php.ini settings

Note that other factors such as memory issues can cause your script to terminate, in which case you are better off using nohup.